# Generate a boolean for where a value in a field matches that in another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have a DataFrame with a field that I want to match to another and create a boolean where one entry exists in another.

Here is an example;

df1:

```
Column1
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
```

df2:

```
Column2
DDD
EEE
FFF
GGG
BBB
```

Result:

```
BooleanResult
True
True
False
False
True
```

The Boolean result is where `Column2` exists in `Column1`

I have been thinking along the lines of using `enumerate()` and `in` somehow

Comment: Check `.isin`..

Comment: Use `df['BooleanResult'] = df2['Column2'].isin(df1['Column1'])`